# Google Places API Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace always returns 0 results in Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-places-api, android-location

I have a question about the PlaceDetection API in Android. I want to get all places near me. On my real device this code works fine, but not in the Emulator, even though i was following step by step the google guide.
Link to the guide: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/location-places-android/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
ListView lstPlaces;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.currentButton);
    lstPlaces = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPlaces);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
            .build();
    currentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                int hasPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                if (hasPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    callPlaceDetectionApi();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch(requestCode){
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
               callPlaceDetectionApi();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" + connectionResult.getErrorCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private void callPlaceDetectionApi() throws SecurityException {
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hioi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hoiha", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()>0){
                    myAdapter.add(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName().toString());
                }
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " +  "likelihood: %g", placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(), placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
            }
            lstPlaces.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
}
```

}

I know there are some issues with location and the Studio Emulator, but why is the google code running and not mine?

[image: Screenshot on working device]

[image: Screenshot on Emulator]

Comment: I know you said you followed that guide, but to confirm (because your screenshots didn't show this): Did you enter a latitude and longitude in the emulator's extended controls dialog?  Does the Google Maps app in the emulator show that location when you press its location button?

Answer (score 0):

On your emulator windows, At the bottom of this bar, you'll see a caret ‘...' control. Select it. This will open the extended controls dialog, and the top item on it will be location.
On the right side of this, enter the location you want ( for exp : use Latitude 49.2772 and Longitude -123.108 ) , after that try to restart your app and it will works , it may take few second for that.